# NSDateFormater, different results on iPhone and iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

When I run this code on iPhone simulator result is 1 (sundey 30. dec, 2012) but when run on iPhone result is 7. Why?

```
 NSCalendar *gregorijan = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

 NSDateFormater * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];
```

......

```
 [dateFormater setDateFormat:[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"e"]];

 NSLog (@"%d",[[dateFormater stringFromDate:self.newDate] integerValue]);

 return [[dateFormater stringFromDate:self.newDate] integerValue];
```

I have different values on iPhone and simulator ...

Comment: why is your date format "e" ?

Comment: I need to now when is Sundey.And I was thinking to use date formater and "e" as patern for week day (http://www.unicode.org/reports/)...

Comment: to know sunday, you need to check nscalender and weekday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set a date format, instead set the date and time style. To short, medium or long. This uses the device locale settings for formatting.

Comment: First day in Gregorian calendar is Sundey?Number 1? Wright? But not same thing is on iOS and iPhone simulator. I have diferent results.